# Building square tapered porch columns that won't rot

Tags: exterior, materials, dry-rot, rot

I have 4 columns originally built with 7 ply plywood and some are starting to rot. I've rebuilt one with cedar but am looking for a material that will last even longer without breaking the bank. The existing columns are square tapered and have no texture.

Is there a readily available product out there that would work ?

Comment: What protective coating if any do you plan to use?  If this coating starts to deteriorate, what will be done if anything?

Comment: Redwood will last longer than cedar. There are trees on the ground in California that folks had their pictures taken back in the metal photograph days and the tree looks the same today.

Comment: Look into PVC boards. ( there are several brands ) I do not know what the cost difference is to cedar but it will last a **LONG**  time.

Comment: @Harper - Was planning to use acrylic latex. Used it on the first column but after 15 years, started to deteriorate. Looking for a longer term solution.